# SVN commit without changes to code

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

Our environment has a UAT repo per application.  All programmers can commit to this repo.  There is also an associated PROD repo per application which only Managers can commit files into from the UAT repo.  The problem we have is if a Manager checks out the necessary files from UAT and attempts to commit into the PROD repo they get an error unless they change something in the files.  How can I stop this?

Comment: So... they are trying to "deploy" from UAT to PROD a second (or third...) time?

Comment: Subversion only tracks changes. If there are no changes to track, there's nothing for Subversion to do. Keeping separate repositories and using them like this is rather unorthodox; most organizations **tag** their releases within the same repository, sometimes (as is my case) after successfully deploying to each environment.

Comment: You say _repo_. Are you talking about _separate_ Subversion repositories, or are you talking about branches in Subversion. When repositories are completely separate, you can't checkout from one repository, do a switch, and check into another repository -- even if both repos are running on the same server. Can you explain your setup in a bit more detail. Also, why isn't what you've setup in UAT being deployed in Production. If files are changed between UAT and Production, you've lost the whole purpose of UAT.

Comment: @DavidW. - "you can't checkout from one repository, do a switch, and check into another repository" - NO, you *can*, under obvious condition: if histories are **not identical*

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason commit to PROD, if UAT have not outstripping history (revision(s), which Managers tested and considered applicable for promoting).

In case of such "diverged" history clean WC of UAT, relocated to PROD, will be transformed into dirty automatically and all inherited changes can be committed immediately